# Como inserir uma imagem usando o Blade do Laravel 5.1

Tags: svg, laravel-5

Se eu preciso inserir um arquivo css ou um script, eu devo fazer respectivamente:

```
<link href="{!! asset('css/style.css') !!}" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
```

Em alguns sites, eu vi que existe algo do tipo (quando se tratava de uma dependência relacionada a uma biblioteca específica):

```
{{ HTML::image('img/picture.jpg') }}
```

Existe alguma forma de eu inserir imagens dentro da minha página HTML diretamente no escopo do arquivo blade sem a necessidade de recorrer a bibliotecas externas?

A minha intenção na verdade é inserir arquivos SVG e sei que se conseguir inserir qualquer `.jpeg` também deve ser possível inserir um `.svg`.

Comment: O .svg é um arquivo estático? Se sim basta fazer com html mesmo, supondo que esteja na pasta `public/assets/images` ficaria assim `<img src="assets/images/arquivo.svg">`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não funciona bem assim pois o Laravel mantém uma segurança de acesso a arquivos por causa dos host's virtuais que estou usando. portanto meu **.htaccess** não deixa usar uma tag assim

Comment: Entendo, talvez eu não tenha entendido como usa o servidor, mas até aonde sei `asset()` gera um path acessivel, ainda sim o que eu quis dizer foi a mesma coisa da sua resposta, usar <img> direto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado @gmsantos mas por incrível que pareça o laravel não aceitou que eu usasse a tag `public_path` e para o laravel 5.1 funcionou perfeitamente como uma referência simples assim:

```
<img src="{!! asset('img/logomarca-c.svg') !!}">
```

Obs: O uso da denotação **{{ }}** está sendo depreciado e no laravel 5.1 o blade já está começando a alterar suas referências para **{!! !!}**

Answer (score 1):

O componente de HTML foi [removido desde o Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) do core do framework.

Você precisa incluir o [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) caso deseje utilizar `{{ HTML::image('img/picture.jpg') }}` ou então use diretamente HTML:

```
<img src="{{ public_path('img/picture.jpg') }}">
```